# AbstractHttpClient.class Source not found

Tags: android, apache, http-post

I am trying to create a simple android app that will communicate with website. The problem I am having is that every time I try and use the HttpPost Eclipse's debugger tells me that: 
Source not Found
The JAR file C:\Users...\android-sdk\plarforms\android-16\android.jar has no source attachment
You can attach the source by clicking Attach Source below:

I tried to attach a few jar files but nothing has worked. Here is my code:

```
    public void onClick(View v) {

    URI website = null;
    HttpResponse response = null;
    BufferedReader in = null;


    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

    try {
        website = new URI("http://fakewebsite.php");
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet();
    getRequest.setURI(website);

    HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost();

    try {
        response = client.execute(postRequest);
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
 response = client.execute(getRequest);
```

instead of

```
 response = client.execute(postRequest);
```

you are getting this error because you are currently not setting URI for

`HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost();`